# authenticate_or_request_with_http_token never pass

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, http-authentication

I am trying to implement an authentication for my rails API following this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast) from railscast. I'm using the method `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`, which I should check the token inside the block and it should pass if the block returns true. However, the method never pass even when I just put true in the block. This is what I see in the log:

I am using rails 4.0

```
  Filter chain halted as :restrict_access rendered or redirected
```

This is my code:

```
  before_filter :restrict_access

  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

You backend have to supply authentication header. For example - 'Authorization' => "Token token=#{@token}". If method doesn't find the header it returns http status 403:Access forbidden

Comment: For anyone using Postman to test their Rails API - it looks like when you select "Bearer Token" as the Authorization method, the header isn't the format that the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method expects. Specifying an "Authorization" header manually, formatted as per the answer above, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using Postman, I got it to work with the following config:

```
Authorization Type: "API Key"
key: "Authorization" 
value: "Token YOUR_TOKEN" (i.e. "Token abcd1234")
Add To: "Header"
```